# Mathematical logic problem about proof

Tags: logic

Problem: Prove that (A → B) ~ (¬A ∨ ¬B).

My book provided tables of truth and I thought that I could make them with this as well, however, it didn't turn out well:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{A → B} & \text{¬A} & \text{¬B} & \text{¬A ∨ ¬B} & \text{(A → B) ~ (¬A ∨ ¬B)}\\ \hline
\text{1.} & T & T & T & F & F & F & F \\ \hline
\text{2.} & T & F & F & F & T & T & F \\ \hline
\text{3.} & F & T & T & T & F & T & T\\ \hline
\text{4.} & F & F & T & T & T & T & T\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

So, it is clear that from my table the statement isn't always true... Could anyone help me with spotting the mistake that I had made?

I had also noticed that since A → B = ¬A v B the question could be rewritten as: (¬A v B) ~ (¬A ∨ ¬B), but as I can see it now (I am just beginning mathematical logic) it doesn't help me.

Problem was solved by noticing that there was a printing error in the textbook, the correct problem was: (A → B) ~ (¬A ∨ B).

Comment: Check the question again... It might be A implies negation of B..Which will make the statement true.

Comment: What does the ~ mean?  If it means "equivelent to", then, of course that's not true!  "If A then B" can't possibly mean "one or the other isn't true".

Comment: @WinVineeth Thank you for the tip, it turns out that the question was printed wrongly.

Comment: And truly obviously $(\lnot A \lor B)$ is not the same thing as $(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$.  "I am not a human being or New York is in the Unitied States" can't possibly be the same as "I am not a human being or New York is not in the United States".

Comment: @fleablood thank you for the comment! It turns out that the question was printed wrongly. Sorry that I took your time!